# Forth mode emacs gforth.el error upon usage

Tags: emacs, forth, gforth

The long and short of it is that I am getting this error message from [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) when I attempt to use gforth.el and open a .fs file:

> Error: Don't know how to compile nil

My [.emacs file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs#Customizability) simply has the following lines.

```
(autoload 'forth-mode "gforth.el")
(autoload 'forth-block-mode "gforth.el")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.fs$" . forth-mode))
```

The directory gforth.el is contained within is in the load path.

Emacs version: 24.3.1

Attempts to byte compile the file yeild the errors/warnings:

```
In toplevel form:
gforth.el:734:18:Error: Don't know how to compile nil
gforth.el:734:18:Error: Don't know how to compile nil
gforth.el:734:18:Error: Don't know how to compile nil
gforth.el:734:18:Error: Don't know how to compile nil
gforth.el:734:18:Error: Don't know how to compile nil

In forth-update-show-screen:
gforth.el:1059:36:Warning: `goto-line' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only
gforth.el:1061:15:Warning: `goto-line' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In end of data:
gforth.el:1697:1:Warning: the function `forth-emacs-older' might not be
    defined at runtime.
```

Comment: Enable "Options => Enter Debugger on Error" from the menu before you get the error.  This should then give you a backtrace that will help track down the source of the problem.

Comment: @Stefan That does not appear to work, as no backtrace or further information is given beyond the above noted error even if that option is active.

Comment: I vaguely remember having this problem too. Here's what I think I did: open the directory containing the `gforth.el` file in `dired`, move the point to the file and press `B`. This will bite-compile the file. If Emacs can't compile the file, it will print the error in the compilation buffer.

Comment: @wvxvw Compilation error added.

Comment: OK, the misbehaving function is `forth-compile-wordlist` in particular the place it calls `(byte-compile 'result)`. What it does is definitely a bug because `result` in that context has no function definition. But I don't quite understand what this code was trying to do. If it bothers you (as in you can't proceed), just comment that line and you'll be fine. But I don't know what you will loose if you do.

Comment: @wvxvw Thank you, that does indeed halt the error cropping up.